# string that contain parentheses to json?

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have the following strings:

```
let string= '{"background": "linear-gradient(to right, #8ca6db, #b993d6)",
    "color": "(rowData, colkey, cellValue, rowIndex) => cellValue > 1 ? gray : white",
    "animation": "0.75s popin"}';
```

I need to pass it to json format, and that it remains as follows.

```
{
    background: "linear-gradient(to right, #8ca6db, #b993d6)",
    color: (rowData, coljey, cellValue, rowIndex) => cellValue > 1 ? "gray" : "white",
    animation: "0.75s popin"
}
```

to be able to use it as a css inside the ng-style tag,
please can someone help me

Comment: Not sure how the code had a string for the arrow function, but somehow it is converted into an actual function. Do you happen to know what could be a function?

Comment: `gray` and `white` doesn't have any quote, what you are looking is coding a Lex / yacc in JS....

Comment: @epascarello  i have this example  [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/IgniteUI/igniteui-live-editing-samples/tree/master/angular-demos/grid/grid-cell-cellStyling?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&view=preview&file=/src/app/grid/grid-conditional-cell-style-2/grid-conditional-cell-style-2.component.ts) 

I need this to be dynamic " public oddColStyles" and  "  public evenColStyles" in example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is not really possible out of the box, it is also not very secure since you need to `eval()` the string to make it a function. This is basically injecting a XSS hole into the application. There would be better ways to do this with includes/configurations, but that really is an architecture change.

If you want to do this, you would need to parse your string into an object. You would have to loop over the object and convert the strings that are functions into a function.

If you know what could be a function it would simple as referencing the property. If you do not, you would need to write something that will detect it is a function. In this example, I am just doing a dirty check which can easily be broken.

```js
const gray = "#CCC";
const white = "#FFF";

const weirdParse = string => {
  const temp = JSON.parse(string);

  Object.keys(temp).forEach(key => {
    if (temp[key].includes("=>")) {
      temp[key] = new Function(`return ${temp[key]}`)()
    }
  });

  return temp;
}

let string = `{"background": "linear-gradient(to right, #8ca6db, #b993d6)",
    "color": "(rowData, colkey, cellValue, rowIndex) => cellValue > 1 ? gray : white",
    "animation": "0.75s popin"}`;

const myObj = weirdParse(string);
console.log(myObj.background);
console.log(myObj.color(1,1,1,1));
console.log(myObj.color(2,2,2,2));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, just what I needed.